# Assigning same integer to specific string for table in database

Tags: python, sql, django, database, postgresql

I'm gathering errors to the table SystemErrors which now looks like this

| id | error_msg | system_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | error1 | 1123 |
| 2 | error1 | 341 |
| 3 | error2 | 1415 |

The message of errors though is too long, so i need another column to the later verification which error it is. And i want in the same table another column which will be connected with Error column. If the row with error1 is added, i want column error_id with integer 1. Like this

| id | error_msg | error_id | system_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | error1 | 1 | 38 |
| 2 | error1 | 1 | 112 |
| 3 | error2 | 2 | 323 |

Now my code looks like this

```
class SystemError(models.Model):
    report = models.ForeignKey(SystemReport, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    error_msg = models.CharField(max_length=2000)
```

Can i do this in this table by assigning any connection with error_msg

Comment: Why don't you use a TextField instead of a CharField? TextField has no length limit.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.